# How do I make the button widgets inside a canvas responsive to the size of the canvas dynamically

Tags: python, tkinter

Python: I  have a  `canvas` with `width=300` that has four button widgets inside horizontally, how do I make the buttons responsive to the size of the canvas? For example; when the `canvas` width is greater than 300 the widgets width should increase to for fit into the `canvas` and when the `canvas` width decreases  the widgets width should also decrease to fit into the `canvas`.

```
import tkinter as tk


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self, bg="grey", height=30)
        self.sidepanel = tk.Frame(self, bg="yellow")
        self.main = tk.Frame(self, bg="turquoise")

        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform=True)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=True)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3, uniform=True)

        self.toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidepanel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.main.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        files_label = tk.Label(self.sidepanel, text="Spectrum Files")
        scrollbarx = tk.Scrollbar(self.sidepanel, orient="horizontal")
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.sidepanel, selectmode="multiple",
                                  yscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
        scrollbarx.configure(command=self.listbox.xview)


        # we'll use `pack` here since there's only one widget that
        # needs to grow or shrink to fit.
        files_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        scrollbarx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.listbox.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas0 = tk.Canvas(self.main, bg="brown")
        self.canvas0.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas0.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20, fill="orange", tags="rectangle",outline='orange')
        self.canvas0.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_canvas_objects)
        self.val = 0.1

        self.list =[]



        for i in range(5):
            self.button= tk.Button(self.canvas0, text=str(i),bd=1)
            self.list.append(self.button)
            self.button.grid(row=4,column=i)



    def resize_canvas_objects(self, event):
        # we'll make the rectangle 1/2 the height of the canvas, with
        # a 10 pixel border
        canvas = event.widget
        self.val+=0.2

        x0, y0 = (10, 10)
        x1, y1 = (event.width - 10, event.height // 2)
        canvas.coords("rectangle", x0, y0, x1, y1)
        ans=(event.width/44.3)
        ans1 = str(ans).split('.')
        padding = str(int(ans))+'.'+ans1[1][0]
        if padding.endswith('0'):
            padding = padding.replace('0','1')
        print(self.val)
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        for i in range(len(self.list)):
            self.list[i].configure(width=int(float(padding)))
            self.list[i].configure(padx=(float(padding)))
            self.list[4].configure(padx=(float(padding)))




    def motion_reader(self,event):
        #print(event.x,event.y)
        k=0






root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

p1 = PageOne(root)
p1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

The buttons are meant to resize progressively.

Comment: Are you expecting the user to be able to scroll the canvas, and have the buttons scroll with the items drawn on the canvas, or do you expect the buttons to remain at the top when the user scrolls the canvas?

Comment: Yes, i expect the buttons to remain at the top of the   canvas , i only want the width to increase to fit into the  canvas dynamically .

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to not give the buttons a width. Let the `grid` geometry manager do all the work. For that to happen, you need to give each column an equal `weight` so that extra space is evenly distributed among the columns. Also, by setting `uniform` for the columns to some non-empty value, they will all be equal in size. You also need to use the `sticky` attribute so that the edges of the buttons will "stick" to the space that is allocated for them.

```
self.canvas0.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2,3, 4), weight=1, uniform=True)

for i in range(5):
    self.button= tk.Button(self.canvas0, text=str(i),bd=1)
    self.list.append(self.button)
    self.button.grid(row=4,column=i, sticky="ew")
```

Then, remove the code in `resize_canvas_objects` that attempts to resize the buttons.

Comment: self.canvas0.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2,3, 4), weight=1, uniform=True)

for i in range(5):
    self.button= tk.Button(self.canvas0, text=str(i),bd=1)
    self.list.append(self.button)
    self.button.grid(row=4,column=i, sticky="ew")
   ................. This approach works absolutely fine . Thank you